# Cant externally connect to my Router aka my http webserver. Huawei

Tags: networking, router

My Router Ip: 192.168.8.1 
My Computer Ip: 192.168.8.2 
My Public Ip: 213.225.14.96

[image]

on my Computer: when i type `localhost` - works. when i type `192.168.8.2` - it works.

But `213.225.14.96` doenst work even with modified port rules?

[image]

Is strange to me :3

Comment: Did you try from inside your local network? Port forwardings often do not work from there. Use a different internet connection (cell phone, …) to test.

Comment: Does _your router_ show you exactly the same WAN IPv4 address as the website does? It seems like your operator has been using CGNAT for IPv4 for a while.

Comment: @Daniel B  sadly still not working.
@user1686!! You were right: the router shows me 10.169.53.177. When i put it in adress bar i get "not reachable" error, but at least no timeout.

Comment: Then it's a duplicate of the many "can't port-forward anymore thanks to CGNAT" threads here. In your case, at least you have IPv6 available (the `2001:4bb8:2e3...` address).